# looking for a command in a batch file to read "wmic diskdrive get serialnumber" and give me an output if a serial number matches

Tags: batch-file, serial-number

looking for a command in a batch file to read "wmic diskdrive get serialnumber" and give me an output if a serial number matches.
So basically im trying to read all serial number outputs and want to display if one matches other wise i want to just continuing running the rest of the operations below it.
alternatively could read all out puts and if theres more then there should be display a warning ie have it hold value a and b but if value c is also found give a warning.

pseudo-code:
`If "wmic diskdrive get serialnumber" outputs a b c, Return, Good to go, Else,  Return, Please check for external drives`

---

but could instead do

---

`If "wmic diskdrive get serialnumber" outputs a b c d, Return, Please check for external drives, Else, Return, Good to go`

Comment: Just one line is required, example: `@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "SerialNumber='3XP3CT3D'" Get Index 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^[0123456789][0123456789]*" 1>NUL && (Echo Good to go) || Echo Please check for external drives`.

Comment: @Compo thank you very much i seem to run into one issue and its with my nvme drive my first three drives show the same serial with wmic and crystal disk but my nvme which is my c drive shoes differnt serials and no matter which one i use it it still returns  Please check for external drives. i have also tried with using both serials at the same time

Picture of what i mean about the serials https://killerpics.tech/i/0t2g3.png

Comment: @Compo its not letting me edit my msg again but could also do it with pnp device id instead as all normal drives show SCSI\ while externals for me show USBSTOR\ just not sure how to do that
tia

Comment: I don't understand how that affects my provided code. If your serial number matches, it will output the appropriate response, if it doesn't it will not. `C:` is not your drive, it is a letter assigned to a volume on a drive, so is not technically relevant here. The issue I assume you're having is that your Drive Manufacturer has a hex type string and the result you're seeing in in the GUI application has successfully converted it. WMIC is not converting it, which is why it is showing differently.

Comment: As a side note, now that you know what WMIC returns you could just expand your `Where` clause, i.e. `Where "SerialNumber='S58SNG0MB10165Y' Or SerialNumber='0025_385B_9150_8B65.'"`. TBH, I probably wouldn't rely on using a serial number anyhow, in my experience, they often have multiple leading and/or trailing spaces, which can also cause issues.